# Differences between STATICFILES_DIR, STATIC_ROOT and MEDIA_ROOT

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles, django-static

What are the differences of these three static url?

I am not sure if I am right, I am using the `MEDIA_ROOT` to store my uploaded photos (via `models.ImageField()`)

However, I created a JS script to my admin and in `admin.py`. I defined the media as below:

```
....
class Media:
      js = ('/admin/custom.js', )
```

and my `settings.py`:

```
 ....
 STATIC_ROOT = "/home/user/project/django1/top/listing/static"
```

and I added the `custom.js` to `STATIC_ROOT/admin/custom.js`, but it is not working. Throwing 404 not found error.

And then I change the `STATIC_ROOT` to `STATICFILES_DIRS`, and it works!!

```
....
STATICFILES_DIRS = "/home/user/project/django1/top/listing/static"
```

So, I am not understand what is going on here. In fact, I just don't understand what is the difference between `STATIC_ROOT` and `STATICFILES_DIRS`.

Currently I am testing Django in my machine via virtualenv, not deployed yet, is it the reason `STATIC_ROOT` not working??

Comment: See also a graphic I've made on how static files work in production: http://djangodeployment.com/2016/11/21/how-django-static-files-work-in-production/

Answer (score 167, accepted):

You can find these settings in the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/). Here are my own definitions and quotations from the documentation:

- `MEDIA_ROOT` is the folder where files uploaded using `FileField` will go.

  > Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold [user-uploaded files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/files/).
- `STATIC_ROOT` is the folder where static files will be stored after using `manage.py collectstatic`

  > The absolute path to the directory where `collectstatic` will collect static files for deployment.
  >
  > If the `staticfiles` contrib app is enabled (default) the `collectstatic` management command will collect static files into this directory. See the howto on managing static files for more details about usage.
- `STATICFILES_DIRS` is the list of folders where Django will search for additional static files aside from the `static` folder of each app installed.

  > This setting defines the additional locations the staticfiles app will traverse if the `FileSystemFinder` finder is enabled, e.g. if you use the `collectstatic` or `findstatic` management command or use the static file serving view.

In your settings, you should have:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media/")
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")

# Make a tuple of strings instead of a string
STATICFILES_DIRS = ("/home/user/project/django1/top/listing/static", )
```

...where:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

as defined in the default Django `settings.py` now.

Comment: This is easily the clearest answer IMO, though I feel like this question is a definite dupe

Comment: @MaximeLorant Honestly, your explanation is better than the Django docs.

Comment: @MaximeLorant beautifully constructed answer. As Jee mentioned, much clearer than the docs themselves.

Answer (score 258):

### Development

`STATIC_ROOT` is useless during development, it's only required for deployment.

While in development, `STATIC_ROOT` does nothing. You don't even need to set it. Django looks for static files inside each app's directory (`myProject/appName/static`) and serves them automatically.

This is the magic done by `manage.py runserver` when `DEBUG=True`.

### Deployment

When your project goes live, things differ. Most likely you will serve dynamic content using Django and static files will be served by Nginx. Why? Because Nginx is incredibly efficient and will reduce the workload off Django.

This is where `STATIC_ROOT` becomes handy, as Nginx doesn't know anything about your Django project and doesn't know where to find static files.

So you set `STATIC_ROOT = '/some/folder/'` and tell Nginx to look for static files in `/some/folder/`. Then you run `manage.py collectstatic` and Django will copy static files from all the apps you have to `/some/folder/`.

### Extra directories for static files

`STATICFILES_DIRS` is used to include **additional** directories for `collectstatic` to look for. For example, by default, Django doesn't recognize `/myProject/static/`. So you can include it yourself.

### Example

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

if not DEBUG:
    STATIC_ROOT = '/home/django/www-data/example.com/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/'),
]
```

Comment: Best explanation for STATIC_ROOT etc. Clear and concise. This is what should be in the django documentation.

Comment: @Max Malysh that's the level of answer we should have. Got it! A+

Comment: You don't even have to add `STATICFILES_DIRS` (if you don't have additional directories to serve file from), you can add `static(...)` function to `urlpatterns` in urls.py, which as stated in docs will work only in Debug mode.

Answer (score 30):

Difference between `STATICFILES_DIRS` and `STATIC_ROOT`

The `STATICFILES_DIRS` can contain other directories (not necessarily app directories) with static files and these static files will be collected into your STATIC_ROOT when you run `collectstatic`. These static files will then be served by your web server and they will be served from your STATIC_ROOT.

If you have files currently in your STATIC_ROOT that you wish to serve then you need to move these to a different directory and put that other directory in `STATICFILES_DIRS`. Your `STATIC_ROOT` directory should be empty and all static files should be collected into that directory.

`MEDIA_ROOT` where media files ,all uploaded files goes.
Example : Images, Files

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Wish that I can accept more than 1 answer for the question. Your answer also very helpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Media:
      js = ('/admin/custom.js', )
```

> but it is not working. Throwing 404 not found error.

The 404 error is in part because of the leading slash in the file path.