# Static Root / Url not working ?

Tags: python, django

In my `settings.py` mention:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

My folder structure

```
project_name
   static
     bootstrap
   settings
      settings.py
```

I am not able to access the static files. Though If I add `STATIC_DIRS`( and comment `STATIC_ROOT`) as below I can access the static files.

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
     os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a difference between static root and staticfiles dirs

`STATICFILES_DIRS` tells django where to look for the static files apart from the standard app directories.

`STATIC_ROOT` tells where to collect all the static files on using the `collectstatic` command.

You need to set `STATIC_ROOT` to some other path from where your webserver (nginx) can server them directly in production.

Comment: For more info, take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24022558/differences-between-staticfiles-dir-static-root-and-media-root

Comment: So both STATIC_DIRS and STATIC_ROOT both I have to define ?

Comment: Yes you need both. But during development only staticfiles_dirs will do.

Comment: I don't know but only when I comment STATIC_ROOT can I access the static files. Is there any order of defining these variables?

Comment: You need to set STATIC_ROOT to some other directory. STATIC_ROOT and STATICFIELS_DIRS should not point to the same directories. There is no fixed order for defining them