# Trying to get image from static folder Django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

I'm trying to display an image located in my static directory. Here is my code :

My directories

[image]

My static settings

[image]

And finally, my template
[image]

Comment: Where are your images/* files currently located? in static older or staticfiles folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a **typo** in your `settings.py`

instead of `STATICFILES_DIR`, add the `S`

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
```

Comment: glad to be of help!

Answer (score 0):

Use below setting

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
]
```

and move your image files to `static` folder

Difference between `STATIC_ROOT`, `STATICFILES_DIRS` and `STATIC_URL` can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24022558/differences-between-staticfiles-dir-static-root-and-media-root)

Comment: STATIC_ROOT can't be the same as STATICFILES_DIRS, and it's the place to collect `static files` for deployment.