# How can I change the default font using in django admin interface?

Tags: python, django, fonts, django-admin

I wanna know how can I change the default font using in django admin interface?

Brgds

Comment: You need to override [django admin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#admin-overriding-templates) and put your custom css there.

Comment: @ruddra can you guide me how? ty

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. Create a folder name `admin` in your [template directory](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/overriding-templates/).
2. Create a file named `base_site.html` in there.
3. Create a css file in your [static directory](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATICFILES_DIRS). for example: `override.css`, where you might put the code for changing font:

   ```
    p {
     font-family : "Fira Code"
    }
    h1 {
     font-family: "Fira Code"
    }
   ```
4. Now update the `base_site.html` like following:

   ```
   {% extends 'admin/base_site.html' %}

   {% load static %}

   {% block extrastyle %}{{ block.super }}<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'override.css' %}" />{% endblock %}
   ```

The `override.css` will change the fonts of `p` and `h1` across admin site. Modify `override.css` according to your need. Hope it helps!!

Comment: I used exactly your code in my base_site.html in my temlate directory but my browser can't find override.css in static directory.

Comment: in browser, did any link with `override.css` appeared? BTW which django version are you using?

Comment: this error solved, whats the difference between STATIC_ROOT and STATICFILES_DIRS? my django version : 2.0.5

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24022558/differences-between-staticfiles-dir-static-root-and-media-root :)