# Pycharm does not load find my static files

Tags: python, css, pycharm

Pycharm cannot find my css files. In the screenshot, the settings.py is shown, along with the directory where the .css is located and the terminal giving back a 404. Can someone kindly point to me where is the problem ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `STATICFILES_DIRS` instead of `STATIC_ROOT`, like this:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

Here's a [SO explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24022558/differences-between-staticfiles-dir-static-root-and-media-root) of the difference between STATICFILES_DIRS and STATIC_ROOT (scroll down to the section that starts with: "...Development
STATIC_ROOT is useless during development, it's only required for deployment.")

Comment: please change it to `STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]` as STATICFILES_DIRS need to  be a list rather than tuple and it works :)