# STATICFILES_DIRS setting makes my admin widget override disappear

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I'm having trouble understanding how static files are handled in Django. I've read through the official Django documentation as well as multiple threads, including this wonderful one here:

[Differences between STATICFILES_DIR, STATIC_ROOT and MEDIA_ROOT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24022558/differences-between-staticfiles-dir-static-root-and-media-root)

Most people define the STATICFILES_DIRS list as a list of paths where django will search for additional static files aside from the app's static folder.

I understand that, but what does this have to do with the formfields I'm overriding in my admin.py?
I have overridden the default ManyToMany form to the FilteredSelectMultiple widget in a few of my admin models like so:

```
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import FilteredSelectMultiple

formfield_overrides = {
    models.ManyToManyField: {'widget': FilteredSelectMultiple("User Names", is_stacked=False)}
}
```

This works fine and produces the widget override I wanted: [Functional Widget Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SI2e7.png)

However, when I define STATICFILES_DIRS in settings.py to include my root static folder like so:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/'),
)
```

It breaks my override and defaults back to the original ManyToMany field form:
[Broken Widget Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0BkV.png)

We do not have STATIC_ROOT defined in our settings.py as we don't plan on using the collect static feature. We plan on keeping/referencing our static files at the root static folder. Also in our settings.py we have:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

I don't understand how these settings for dealing with static files are interfering with the formfield_override above. I would appreciate some insight on this, so that I could find a way to approach this issue.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the cause of my issue. I missed this portion in the Django documentation that explains STATICFILES_FINDERS: [STATICFILES_STORAGE Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATICFILES_STORAGE)

[image]

It turns out that my production server was finding the static files in my outer root folder first, which were not up to date. This explains why I wasn't seeing my changes. I'm going to reconfigure the way I handle static files to ensure that the outer root static folder that my production server looks always has the latest static files via the `collectstatic` feature