# CSS file won't load - Django

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm having trouble loading my CSS files. The browser that I'm using is Chrome. 
Here are my codes and file directories.
Thanks!

[file directories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C53Qh.png)

• ecommerce/ecommerce/settings.py

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
....

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'store.apps.StoreConfig',
]

....

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'


STATICFILES_DIRS = [
  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
]
```

• ecommerce/ecommerce/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('store.urls'))
]
```

• ecommerce/ecommerce/static/css/main.css

```
body{
    background-color:blue;
}
```

• ecommerce/ecommerce/store/templates/store/store.html

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}">

<h3>store</h3>

<img src="{% static 'images/cart.png' %}">
```

• ecommerce/ecommerce/store/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
        #Leave as empty string for base url
    path('', views.store, name="store"),
    path('cart/', views.cart, name="cart"),
    path('checkout/', views.checkout, name="checkout"),

]
```

• ecommerce/ecommerce/store/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
def store(request):
     context = {}
     return render(request, 'store/store.html', context)

def cart(request):
     context = {}
     return render(request, 'store/cart.html', context)

def checkout(request):
      context = {}
      return render(request, 'store/checkout.html', context)
```

Comment: Did you do ```py manage.py collectstatic```? Is it only css or static image also does not show?

Comment: Yes, and I got an error - "django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: You're using the staticfiles app without having set the STATIC_ROOT setting to a filesystem path."

Comment: Whats the error ??

Comment: "django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: You're using the staticfiles app without having set the STATIC_ROOT setting to a filesystem path."

Comment: Okay... the answer must solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break this down: You are in development, right? (at least it seems like you are since you have `DEBUG = True`). Well, when in development, Django serves the staticfiles by itself. He does it by looking for folders called **static** inside each app directory. (this is the [default behaviour](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#staticfiles-finders))

In your project structure, as shown in the image you attached with your question, there's no **static** directory inside your `store` app.

You should have something like this:

```
store/
|   templates/
|   |   (... all your templates )
|   static/
|   |   store/
|   |   |   css/
|   |   |   |   main.css
|   |   |   images/
|   |   |   |   cart.png
|   (... all your other .py files )
```

*please note:* In that same image that you attached, I can see that you named the css file as "mian.css" instead of "main.css"

Now, as it was well said in [this marvelous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40330875/7303434), you don't need to set in development the `STATIC_ROOT` nor the `STATICFILES_DIRS` settings, since you will not be using `collectstatic` there, because `manage.py` will take care of everything about serving the static files. So, again: not use `collectstatic` in development. There's no need for that.

Lastly, you will need to reference the files in your template properly. You can do it as follows:

```
{% static 'store/css/main.css' %}
```

and

```
{% static 'store/images/cart.png' %}
```

respectively.

Comment: I got another error - django.core.management.base.SystemCheckError: SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
?: (staticfiles.E002) The STATICFILES_DIRS setting should not contain the STATIC_ROOT setting.

Comment: This is because you have both `STATIC_ROOT` and the entry in `STATICFILES_DIRS` pointing to the same directory. STATICFILES_DIRS is used to include additional directories for collectstatic, so if you don't actually need that setting, just get rid of it.

Comment: I made the changes but still can't load the CSS file. In fact, I opened up the developer tool in Chrome and it says "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"

Comment: OMG it works!!!! You are a hero, sir! Thank you very much. Question for you, do you have any projects you've done in the past that I could possibly take a look at? I'm still new to Django and really want to learn more. If you have other recommendations or advice please let me know. Again, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In your URLs.py,

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^$', include('frontend.urls')),
);


urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Make sure that your settings.py file has these defined.

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../static')

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
)
```

Also, in your templates add on the top:

```
{%load staticfiles%}
```

Comment: ImportError: cannot import name 'url' from 'django.urls' (/Users/nnakamura/Desktop/ecommerce/virtual/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/__init__.py)

Comment: I did what you told me but it keeps giving me errors