# static files not found 404 django on development server

Tags: python, django, apache, ubuntu, asgi

i couldn't find a solution after trying alot of solutions here, my problem is i'm running an ASGI app on a devlopement server and i can't get static files nor urls,it's working perfectly on local but not in server

this server is running ubuntu and using apache2, i couldn't deploy because apache don't support asgi so i wanted just to run it as local , this is the apache conf on server

```
ProxyPass /checkAuth2 http://localhost:8000
ProxyPassReverse /checkAuth2 http://localhost:8000
ProxyPreserveHost On
```

so to run the app i should go to http://server/checkAuth2

settings.py
BASE_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(**file**))

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'channels',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'checkurl',
]




 STATIC_URL = '/static/'
print(BASE_DIR)
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
```

index.html

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'checkurl/css/bootstrap.min.css' %} ">
  <script src="{% static 'checkurl/js/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'checkurl/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
```

path of static folder:edit
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JnXb.png)

when i run server : i get this url http://server/checkAuth2/checkurl
and for the files i get  : http://server/checkurl/static/css.. which's not found

i appreciate your help about this as i'm stuck here for 3 days, thank you!

Comment: Please, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62240629/7303434) I gave for a similar question. It might be helpful for your case

Comment: thank u for ur answer,i saw the answer and i don't see a problem with the structure, i edited my answer with the capture