# My static (CSS) files are loading for my Django website, but they are not being displayed. What am I missing or doing wrong?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

EDIT:
I figured out that the CSS file was not being displayed because I copied the link tag pointing to the CSS file from Microsoft Word, so the quotations marks around rel="stylesheet" were not the right type of quotations marks!!

The settings.py file in the project folder defines the STATIC_URL variable as '/static/'

The CSS file is inside the app folder: DjangoProject/shop/static/shop/style.css

The {% load static %} is at the top of the HTML template (if I use "staticfiles" instead of "static", I get an error)

The CSS file is linked using href="{% static 'shop/style.css' %}"

The CSS file loads and is visible when I analyze the "view page source", but the actual CSS is not displayed on the webpage.

What am I doing wrong? I'm using Django version 3.0.7

EDIT:

I've also tried defining the STATICFILES_DIRS in the settings.py file, but that doesn't do anything. Nor does adding the additional code below to the project urls.py file.

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
```

.

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

urlpatterns = [
    #your url patterns
]
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

[image: Image of my code]

Comment: Do you have django.contrib.staticfiles inside of your `INSTALLED_APPS` in settings.py? 

It would be more beneficial if you included your actual code in stead of an image.

Comment: Yes, 'django.contrib.staticfiles', is there in the INSTALLED_APPS list.

Answer (score 1):

you have to add

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
```

in your settings.py file below `STATIC_URL`

add bolew code in main urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

urlpatterns = [
    #your url patterns
]
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

and make sure you are hard refreshing the webpage and try restarting server

Comment: Is this the same as declaring the `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')` in the sttings.py?

Comment: I've tried that, and I just tried it again, but that doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: I've tried adding something similar to the urls.py file before, but I always get an error. With the code you provided, I get "NameError: name 'staticfiles_urlpatterns' is not defined". How can I fix this NameError?

Comment: no it's not same @plum0 https://stackoverflow.com/a/24022604/11602126

Comment: @b0302 I edited the answer again included a import see it

Comment: if need any further help just comment

Comment: The import of staticfiles_urlpatterns fixes the NameError, but it still does not display the CSS, even after restarting the server :\

Comment: @Pavankumar Oh, that post helped me so much understand the difference between these settings! Thank you! The django documentation on it got me a bit lost but that person laid it out in a way I could comprehend.