# AttributeError: 'WindowsPath' object has no attribute 'endswith'

Tags: python, django

When I run my project this error comes.

```
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mowgli\anaconda3\envs\surajDjangoEnv\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Mowgli\anaconda3\envs\surajDjangoEnv\lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Mowgli\anaconda3\envs\surajDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Mowgli\anaconda3\envs\surajDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 118, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\Mowgli\anaconda3\envs\surajDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 396, in check
    databases=databases,
  File "C:\Users\Mowgli\anaconda3\envs\surajDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 70, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "C:\Users\Mowgli\anaconda3\envs\surajDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\checks.py", line 9, in check_finders
    finder_errors = finder.check()
  File "C:\Users\Mowgli\anaconda3\envs\surajDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\finders.py", line 81, in check
    if prefix.endswith('/'):
AttributeError: 'WindowsPath' object has no attribute 'endswith'
```

Comment: I don't declare WindowsPath anywhere and don't import them why has this error come?

Comment: Show us your settings (excluding private information)! Which Django version are you using?

Comment: Hi Suraj, please provide the relevant code. It should however be enough, if you change your code to something like if  str(prefix).endswith('/') to solve the specific issue here. But since you don't explain, what you are trying to do, it is hard to guess, if there might be a better solution.

Comment: @n00by0815 The code is in the Django library, changing it there would create update troubles. I suspect faulty data or a bug in Django.

Comment: @KlausD. You are right and I am sorry I didn't properly read the error message. Still his OS (Although from the paths it looks like windows) as well as his Python/Anaconda and Django version are missing. And I don't seem to see any path in his traceback, that he presumeably set somewhere in his code. Maybe he just set it to Path(something) instead of just providing a path in string format. Hard to tell

Comment: @KlausD I use Django version 3.1.1

Comment: And the settings?

Comment: # Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
TEMPLATE_DIR= BASE_DIR, 'template'
STATIC_DIR = BASE_DIR, 'static'
MEDIA_DIR= BASE_DIR, 'media'

Comment: # Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'debug_toolbar',
    'basic_app'
]

Comment: TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_DIR],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

Comment: # Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS= [STATIC_DIR,]

#Media
MEDIA_ROOT= MEDIA_DIR
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
LOGIN_URL = '/basic_app/ user_login'

Comment: @KlausD. is this helpful?

Comment: Please add all relevant information to the question itself. It is unreadable in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

You can get parts of WindowsPath object with property *parts*. Select the last part and use the *endswith* attribute.

```
import pathlib
import os

path_to_here = pathlib.Path(os.getcwd())
last_part = path_to_here.parts[-1]
print(last_part.endswith('ending'))
```

Answer (score 0):

"""
Django settings for the learning_user project.

Generated by 'Django-admin start project' using Django 3.1.1.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path

## Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.

Answer (score 0):

This error happens due to the configuration of static files

Try this:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static",
]

STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / "staticfiles"

MEDIA_URL = "/media/"

MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / "media"
```

You don't have to use the os module, it not necessary. BASE_DIR already defined in your settings.py file.

STATICFILES_DIRS is used in deployment. If you want, you can delete it for now.

[click for detailed explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24022604/13220068)