# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/app/static'

Tags: django, heroku

I got this error when trying to host my django project on heroku `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/app/static'`
here is settings.py:

```
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

and this is the error :

```
 File "/app/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/app/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 187, in handle
    collected = self.collect()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 105, in collect
    for path, storage in finder.list(self.ignore_patterns):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/finders.py", line 130, in list
    for path in utils.get_files(storage, ignore_patterns):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/utils.py", line 23, in get_files
    directories, files = storage.listdir(location)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 316, in listdir
    for entry in os.scandir(path):
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/app/static'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The differences between `STATICFILES_DIRS`, `STATIC_ROOT`, `MEDIA_ROOT`, etc. [can be confusing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24022558). In your case, you can start by removing the first line of your `settings.py`, because [`STATIC_DIR` is not a Django settings variable](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/#static-files).

Then, the actual cause of your problem is that directory specified in the Django's settings variable `STATICFILES_DIRS` does not exist:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
```

On the Heroku server, this path is `/app/static`, but on you own computer it likely lives in a location such as `$HOME/awesome-django-project/static`. Creating the directory there will hopefully solve the problem.

Alternatively, you could remove the setting `STATICFILES_DIRS` altogether and place your staticfiles [inside app directories](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/#staticfiles-finders). I personally prefer this approach because it makes the settings simpler and your source code directory cleaner.