# Static Root Issue - Static files won't load deploying to pythonanywhere

Tags: python, django, path, pythonanywhere, django-staticfiles

I'm currently trying to deploy my project and I can't seem to get my static files working correctly like they did on my local environment using the collectstatic command. The service I am deploying on is pythonanywhere - this is where I'm at right now. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**settings.py**

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static",
    BASE_DIR/"static"/"images",
    BASE_DIR/"static"/"css"
]

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/images')

MEDIA_URL = '/images/'

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'

LOGIN_URL = 'login'
```

**My file structure**
[image: File structure]

**Pythonanywhere Path**
[image: Pythonanywhere Path]

Answer (score 0):

Try providing a STATIC_ROOT directory in your settings (this is where files will be collected by collectstatic, so you may have one already), eg,

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
```

Next, make sure that on the webpage tab your Directory value includes the name of this folder - in this case it's likely to be home/HFShippingLLC/mysite/static.  This should essentially be the same value as static_root.

The URL value on the web tab isn't appended on to the directory value, which is where I think you might have come unstuck. Instead, it's an alias - so when the browser requests /static/ it looks in home/HFShippingLLC/mysite/static

There's a great explanation of the various STATIC settings in this question: [Differences between STATICFILES_DIR, STATIC_ROOT and MEDIA_ROOT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24022558/differences-between-staticfiles-dir-static-root-and-media-root)

NB: You should have DEBUG = False in your settings.py if you are wanting to use STATIC_ROOT, and making changes to settings in pythonanywhere usually requires a reload of the site via the web tab.

Comment: I got collectstatic to run and copy all my files to the designated location, changing my code in settings.py to this:

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR/"static"/"images",
    BASE_DIR/"static"/"css"
]

As well as the path on the website to this:

home/HFShippingLLC/mysite/static

However, nothing is able to be loaded from the static directory still, any ideas?

Comment: Did you reload the website on the web tab?

Comment: Yep, the directory was not empty when I ran the collectstatic command - is that okay?

Comment: Yes -that will happen  if you've run it before or included it in an upload.  Another thing to check is that you have DEBUG = False in your settings file for this environment.

Comment: I've had it set to True, should I change it to False?

Comment: When I uploaded the static directory, I uploaded everything that I had on my local environment that was static related. To me - that seems like the common sensical thing to do but I read on that thread you linked that the directory should be empty and if you're using existing files they should be included in a different directory and added to STATICFILES_DIRS. Swapping debug to false presents me the same error.

Comment: i.e GET https://hfshippingllc.pythonanywhere.com/static/images/register.png 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Running the collectstatic command should go through all your apps and copy their /static folder contents and file structures (as well as any other folders you nominate in your STATICFILES_DIRS) into your STATIC_ROOT directory - basically so you don't have to.  You can easily delete it and run collectstatic again, but the original /static directories in your app folders will need to still be there to be copied from.

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer by making many changes, all of which were consistent with this answer found below - as well as this learn django guide which I will also link here:

[Why does DEBUG=False setting make my django Static Files Access fail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836674/why-does-debug-false-setting-make-my-django-static-files-access-fail/49889262#49889262)

https://learndjango.com/tutorials/django-static-files